# javascript callbacks on a "static method"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that I can use callbacks like this:

```
function foo(mySuccess) {

    $.post('handler.ashx', mySuccess);
}
```

But how would I do in the following scenario:

```
function foo(){ }

$.post('handler.ashx', function(){

    foo.mySuccess = function(data); //this wont work, but you get the idea
});
```

And then call it using:

```
foo.mySuccess(function(data){

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post('handler.ashx', foo.mySuccess);
```

This is under the assumption that the object has an accessible `mySuccess` function.

For example:

```
var foo = (function(){

    return {
       mySuccess: function(data) {
          console.log(data)
       }
    };

})()
```

Comment: I think is worth noting that the function will lose the binding unless `Function.prototype.bind` is used.

Comment: @RenatoZannon whatever do you mean?

Comment: if `foo.mySucess` uses `this`, it will be `null` or `window` (instead of `foo`) when it is called as a callback. It is a common gotcha

Comment: @RenatoZannon that is not true at all. I can use `this` inside of the function however I want. [**see here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wn8e2/)

Comment: actually, you can't. I hope [the fiddle I made](http://jsfiddle.net/Wn8e2/1/) helps to clarify that.

Comment: @RenatoZannon interesting... [look at the indirect result](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Wn8e2/3/)

Comment: @RenatoZannon [I have asked a question based on your fiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13459992/561731)

Answer (score 1):

To maintain your API (calling a `mySuccess` function with a callback, instead of defining it), you could leverage [jQuery's promises/deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
var foo = (function() {
  function foo() {};
  foo.mySuccess = $.post("handler.ashx").promise().done;
  return foo;
})();
```

Then, use it as `foo.mySuccess`, as on your example:

```
foo.mySuccess(function(data) {
  // use data
});
```

Note that this has the nice side-effect accepting multiple callbacks.